# How can I obscure the requested asset's file path when serving an Apache error page?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, permissions

Our server uses the following rewrite rule to obscure our image locations, which directs `www.domain.com/media/*` to `www.domain.com/secret/sub/directory/to/images/`:

```
RewriteRule ^media/(.*) /secret/sub/directory/to/images/$1
```

This works well when a valid image is served, but when an invalid asset URL is requested, the 404 notice displays the full real file path instead of the user-friendly URL. (I've also noticed it happen for 403s as well).

For example:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /secret/sub/directory/to/images/image.png was not found on this server.

Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at www.domain.com Port 443
```

How can I convince the server to show the user-facing URL instead of the full file path?

Comment: Please show the ruleset you are using to accomplish this.

Comment: @MikeRockett Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with the following ruleset instead:

```bash
RewriteEngine on

# If the file requested exists in the images directory
# then serve it as if it were in media.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/media/(.+) [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/secret/sub/directory/to/images/%1 -f
RewriteRule ^ /secret/sub/directory/to/images/%1 [L]
```

The first condition checks to see if we are requesting from `media` and, if so, passes along that filename to the next condition, which checks to see if what we're requesting actually exists in the secret directory.

If both conditions pass, then the request is internally rewritten to the secret directory using the backreference to the captured part of the first condition (`(.+)` => `%1`).

If the file requested does not exist in the secret directory, then the internal rewritting is skipped, and Apache will show that `/media/non-existent.png` does not exist on the server.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I had to change `^` to `^media/(.+)` in the last line, but all good from there.

Comment: That shouldn't matter due to the condition, but if it works, then it works. You're most welcome.